# Renaming devices in intune via Powershell

Tags: powershell, intune, microsoft-graph-intune, device-management

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that allows me to update all the names of our devices in Intune [430ish devices] to reflect our asset tags. When they were imported into our tenant, they were given the serialNumber of the device as their deviceName. All permissions for the API have been applied:

```
API Permissions:
Device Read
Device Read all
DeviceManagementApps.ReadAll
DeviceManagementApps.ReadWriteAll
DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadAll
DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWriteAll
DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All
DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadAll
DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWriteAll
DeviceManagementRBAC.ReadAll
DeviceManagementRBAC.ReadWriteALL
DeviceManagementServiceConfig.ReadAll
DeviceManagementServiceConfig.ReadWriteAll
User Read
```

This is the code as far as I can get it, but I am still getting the following error [I apologise for ugly or poorly formatted code, I have had no formal training, all learnt using google-fu!]:

```
# Setting variables for connecting to the MS API 
$ApplicationID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$TenantDomainName = "contoso.com"
$AccessSecret = Read-Host "Enter Secret"

# Connect to MSGraph command to run
Connect-MSGraph

# Setting the body of the json
$Body = @{    
Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
client_Id     = $ApplicationID
Client_Secret = $AccessSecret
} 

# Authenticating the connection to MSGraph
$ConnectGraph = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantDomainName/oauth2/v2.0/token" `
-Method POST -Body $Body

$token = $ConnectGraph.access_token

# Importing the CSV of device information
$csvfile = "C:\<Path to file>"
Import-Csv $csvfile | ForEach-Object {
    $serialNumber = $_.serialNumber;
    $tag = $_.tag;
    $deviceId = $serialNumber
    Write-Host "Renaming machine from: $deviceID to: $tag" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    # Getting the Device from the CSV and then putting it into MSGraph compatible Json
    $DeviceToRename = Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter ("serialNumber eq '$serialNumber'")
        Foreach ($Device in $DeviceToRename) {
                $Resource = "deviceManagement/managedDevices('$DeviceId')/setDeviceName"
                $graphApiVersion = "Beta"
                $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/executeAction"

#This JSON format doesnt work
#    $JSONPayload = @"
#    {  <NEW>
#        "body":  <NEW>
#        {
#            action: "setDeviceName",
#            actionName: "setDeviceName",
#            deviceName: "$tag",
#            realaction: "setDeviceName",
#            restartNow: false
#       }
#    }  <NEW>
#"@

  #Don't know if this works properly either?
    $JSONPayload = @"
        {
           "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.managedDevice",
           "actionName": "setDeviceName",
           "deviceName": "$tag"
        }
"@

# Writing out to check if this is working correctly
Write-Host $JSONPayload

# Converting $JSONPayload to an actual workable JSON
$convertedJSON = ConvertTo-Json $JSONPayload

try {
    Invoke-MSGraphRequest -Url $uri -HttpMethod PATCH -Body $JSONPayload -ContentType "application/Json"  -Verbose
} catch {
    # Dig into the exception to get the Response details.
    Write-Host "StatusCode:" "$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__" 
    Write-Host "StatusDescription:" "$_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription"
    Write-Host "StatusCode2:" "$_.ErrorDetails.Message"
        }
     }
}
```

Error response:

```
StatusCode: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Body'..Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
StatusDescription: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Body'..Exception.Response.StatusDescription
StatusCode2: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Body'..ErrorDetails.Message
```

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems some months ago manipulating intune devices from an powershell runbook over graph. In my case the json body was the problem. I had to define the body first as hashtable and then convert it to json. Try something like this:

```
# JSONPayload as hashtable instead of string
$JSONPayload = @{
    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.managedDevice"
    "actionName" = "setDeviceName"
    "deviceName" = "$tag"
}

# Writing out to check if this is working correctly
$JSONPayload

# Converting $JSONPayload to an actual workable JSON
$convertedJSON = $JSONPayload | ConvertTo-Json
```

And then pass the `$convertedJSON` to your graph call as body:

```
Invoke-MSGraphRequest -Url $uri -HttpMethod POST -Content $convertedJSON -Verbose
```

**EDIT:**
You are calling the endpoint `/deviceManagement/managedDevices/executeAction` with the http method `PATCH`. According to this [ms docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-executeaction?view=graph-rest-beta) you have to call the endpoint with the http method `POST`.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for taking the time to respond!

The current write-host $JSONPayload is

```
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```
With the same issue about the -Body not being a parameter that can be used.

I am wondering if I am using the correct Invoke?

Comment: `Write-Host` is to print out strings. As `$JSONPayload` is a hashtable I've removed the `Write-Host` part to write out the HT content. Further I checked the `Invoke-MSGraphRequest` cmdlet. `-ContentType` does not exist (removed). `-Body` does not exist (changed to `-Content`). And I found this article which covers exactly your case: https://msendpointmgr.com/2020/03/02/how-to-rename-windows-10-devices-in-intune-using-powershell/ (I hope this will help)

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to respond! I had seen this script early on in my research for this, and couldn't work out how I could apply this to my already pre-defined assettags that we have already stuck on the laptops. 

However using `-Content` could be the resolution I need, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @Tom-D , let me know if it works with `-Content` :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am pretty sure that I am doing something very wrong. I have managed to get the devices in AAD to be renamed, albeit one at a time, however trying to get this working for intune devices seems to be elusive!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently testing this for a customer, will post back with my results.

This assumes you know how to create an azure app registration, if not see this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

I am using API to get a list of autoPilotdevices:

```
$autoPilotUri ="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/windowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities"

$AutoPilotInventory = ( Invoke-GraphRequest -Uri $autoPiloturi -Method Get -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction Stop )
```

Loop through inventory (you'll need to set the new name etc.):

```
foreach ($device in $AutoPilotInventory | where-object {$_.enrollmentState -eq "enrolled"}) { 

$mgdDevice = Get-MgDeviceManagementManagedDevice -managedDeviceId $device.managedDeviceId

$updatedName = $someNewNamingcovention

Set-MgDeviceManagementManagedDeviceName -managedDeviceId $device.managedDeviceId -DeviceName $updatedName  
}
```

---

Update: This worked.  Renamed Intune, AutoPilot, AzureAD device name(s).  it does require a reboot of the device, to show the updated name in the portal.  The job will show completed, but name will not update until the device is restarted which makes sense.